# How to use dowloaded Google Fonts in my app offline?

Tags: html, css, fonts, truetype, google-font-api

I have downloaded a couple of fonts in a folder of my app in my `www/css` folder:

```
/Oxygen
```

This folder consist of:

```
Oxygen-Bold.ttf
Oxygen-Light.ttf
```

In the traditional way, you include a link like the following in your index.html to have access to these font styles, e.g.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700|Oxygen:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

However, since I want my fonts to be available **offline**, I am wondering what steps I need to undertake to be able to use these fonts as well?

Comment: do you need to use the .woff extension, can you also link it to the .ttf?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to download the font as a `.ttf` according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27696481/3400962.

Comment: This question was already answered somewhere else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930003/downloading-a-google-font-and-setting-up-an-offline-site-that-uses-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, the CSS generated by Google Fonts depends on the requesting user agent as every browser uses different font formats, that are TTF, EOT, WOFF, WOFF2 and SVG. There is no way to directly download all font variants directly from Google, other than faking the user agent and inspecting the generated CSS rules.

You can use a tool like http://www.localfont.com/ to download all font formats and automatically generate cross browser CSS rules.

Comment: Or with just changing the extension when downloading the font files ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately not. The filenames are hashes and different for every format. For exmaple compare TTF and WOFF for Oxygen bold:
http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/oxygen/v5/yVHpdQrmTj9Kax1tmFSx2qCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf
http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/oxygen/v5/yVHpdQrmTj9Kax1tmFSx2rO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff - Try changing the extension for one or the other and you will get a 404.

Comment: Too bad, it definitely worked for a while. Google is getting smarter lol

Comment: Yeah, they make it unnecessarily hard.