# What is the best way set IOS and Android fonts to my sencha-touch/phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

What is the best way to set IOS and Android fonts to my sencha-touch/phonegap app?

I'm using sencha-touch 2 with phonegap 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

So how Phonegap is just a web application, then you can use any ways to install custom fonts.

I recommend to follow the instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18648083/2413972).
In my opinion this is the best way.