# How to use Google Web Font in website form local path?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am working on new website with adding google font but when i disable my internet google font not working not showing offline mode. How can I set google font but link form my local folder not form google server?

Used html method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
```

Used css method:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

Comment: You can use the `file://` prefix (e.g. `file://c:/Users/myuser/fonts/myfont.ttf`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to download Open Sans as available on Google Fonts to use on my desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170113/is-it-possible-to-download-open-sans-as-available-on-google-fonts-to-use-on-my-d)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'),
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(OpenSans-Light.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(OpenSans-Light.ttf) format('truetype');

}
```

Download [Google Font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open%20Sans)

Answer (score 1):

Download font files and put them into a folder inside your root folder. And link it inside your HTML like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf" />
```

Another possible solution is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930264/3958365).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [goog-webfont-dl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/goog-webfont-dl) to download fonts locally.
This will also generate css file for you to use in your project.