# Not sure how to apply custom fonts in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, custom-font

So I've checked out another question being answered on this and attempted this on my own. I want to use the Lobster two font and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cogna</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="site">
    <tr>
        <td id="Cogna">Cogna</td>
        <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">a</td>
        <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">a</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two';
    src: url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two");
}

#Cogna {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', Times, serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 18pt;
    width: 20%
}

#site {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I know I've asked it to replace with Times New Roman if it can't find the font, but I really want to use the font.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Edit: this is the exact link to the font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lobster+Two.

Comment: You sure that's the correct URL? You're missing an essential part.

Comment: @chazsolo I am a bit new to CSS and kind of mixed the link I got here: http://www.cssfontstack.com/Lobster-Two, to my CSS.

Comment: Please take a look at Google's excellent developer documentation on adding custom fonts. Very well written and easy to follow. https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

Comment: Please if you are just learning don't learn to code using tables. Tables are not made for page layouts. http://www.beginnersguidetohtml.com/guides/css/layout/div-tags

Answer (score 2):

Referencing a link to the font is fine, but downloading the font is preferable. I did mine according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696481/5472966).

1. Go to https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts
2. Pick the font(s) you want and download the files
3. Drop in the generated CSS from the page, and reference the CSS file in your HTML like so:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/styles.css">
   ```

Answer (score 1):

2 Method in order to add Google font :

**Standard :**

Add this in the head of your html file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">`

**CSS:**

Apply the family to which ever elements you choose in your style.css file such as:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google is friendly enough to give you a step by step guide on how to use their fonts.

[image]

More details on [their wiki](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this
`src: url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two");`
into this`src: url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two");`

Answer (score 0):

Try including the font using this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two');
```

instead of

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Lobster Two';
src: url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use this in your html file: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Lobster+Two" rel="stylesheet">
```

add this in your css where you want to apply the font there

```
font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
```

try this .. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In the style sheet use

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two');
```

Then where you want to apply the font:

```
font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
```