# How do install fonts using npm?

Tags: npm, fonts, webfonts

I want to install fonts using npm, for example, [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) or [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto). 
If I search for Open Sans on npm and filter for packages with over 1000 downloads per month I find a whole list. I am not sure which source to choose here, some are not well maintained and none of them are from the original source of the font, in this case, google.

- [npm-font-open-sans](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-font-open-sans)
- [typeface-open-sans](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-open-sans)
- [open-sans-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-sans-all)
- [open-sans-fontface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-sans-fontface)
- [opensans-npm-webfont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opensans-npm-webfont)

I noticed that fonts are [often](https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/blob/master/gae/framebox.tpl) used through a direct link to fonts.googleapis. I would prefer to have a local copy of the font to be able to develop offline. Is there a common way to install fonts through npm? Or is there another automated font download tool that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading a Google font and setting up an offline site that uses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930003/downloading-a-google-font-and-setting-up-an-offline-site-that-uses-it)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

<strike>I use [typefaces](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typefaces) `yarn add typeface-roboto`</strike>

and then just do a `require("typeface-roboto")` / `import "./typeface-roboto"` or whatever font you choose.

<strike>I hope this is the answer you're looking for?</strike>

Use [fontsource](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource), typefaces is deprecated now.

```
yarn add @fontsource/open-sans // npm install @fontsource/open-sans
```

Then within your app entry file or site component, import it in. For example in Gatsby, you could choose to import it into a layout template (layout.js), page component (index.js), or gatsby-browser.js.

```
import "@fontsource/open-sans" // Defaults to weight 400 with all styles included.
```

Fontsource allows you to select weights and even individual styles, allowing you to cut down on payload sizes to the last byte! Utilizing the CSS unicode-range selector, all language subsets are accounted for.

```
import "@fontsource/open-sans/500.css"; // All styles included.
import "@fontsource/open-sans/900-normal.css"; // Select either normal or italic.
```

Alternatively, the same solutions could be imported via SCSS!

```
@import "~@fontsource/open-sans/index.css";
@import "~@fontsource/open-sans/300-italic.css";
```

Comment: Well, how i use in a specific tag only? <p> Hi </p>

Comment: off the top of my head, css

Comment: As of version 4.0.x the `-normal` suffix is deprecated; you must leave it off when loading just the normal styles. https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#40x

Answer (score 6):

## Fontsource

The typefaces project is now [deprecated](https://github.com/kyleamathews/typefaces) and its successor is [fontsource](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource).

### Usage

There's no much difference at the point of using it.

Install:

```
yarn add @fontsource/open-sans // npm install @fontsource/open-sans
```

Import:

```
import "@fontsource/open-sans"
```

Reference:

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```