# font picker in angular 2 and above for a system where there is no internet connection

Tags: angular

I have been struggling last few days in implementing font picker in angular.

I have implemented font picker using the 'ngx-font-picker' in angular 2 and above but it requires google API call to be made. The system does not have any internet connection. how do I download the google fonts to local system and bind it to font picker.

ngx-font-picker:

[image]

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930003/downloading-a-google-font-and-setting-up-an-offline-site-that-uses-it

Comment: @AkberIqbal Thanks for your quick reply. I am unable to understand how the downloaded fonts will be binded to a font picker..