# How to use combination of google fonts in offline mode

Tags: fonts, combinations, offline

I am using google fonts in my webpage by using the link :

[https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Nunito:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i"](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i%7CNunito:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i%7CPoppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i%22)

Now I need to run my website over intranet where open internet does not exists. How can I download this font combination and use it offline please.

for single font solution is right here at :
[Downloading a Google font and setting up an offline site that uses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930003/downloading-a-google-font-and-setting-up-an-offline-site-that-uses-it)

but for combination of fonts I could not find any solution yet.